# How to calculate last months as a period and update to chart by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to update the chart based on time period.

currently chart is updating all values for 3,6,9,12 months from january to December

Now i need to update the chart by

- last 3 months - (means current month is december so i need to get the chart for Dec, nov, october)
- last 6 months (Dec, nov, october, september,August,july)
- last 9 months (Dec, nov, october, september,August, july, june, may, april)
- January to this month (get the chart for january to current month)

I am already calculating the current month, but i dont know how to attach to chart.

one more thing i am calling same chart function, thrice, is there a way to make it less code. i tried but i am not able to figure it out.

Any help is Appreciated

### JSFIDDLE

**http://jsfiddle.net/jygh8obh/22/**

Html

```
<select id="chartType">
<option value="bar">bar chart</option>
<option value="area">area chart</option>
<option value="line">line chart</option>
<option value="spline">spline chart</option>
</select>

<select id="SelectPeriod" >
<option value="3">January to this month</option>
<option value="3">Last 3 months</option>
<option value="6">Last 6 months</option>
<option value="9">Last 9 months</option>
<option value="12">Last 12 months</option>
</select>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var data = [
['data4', 'data2', 'data3'],
[90, 120, 300],
[40, 160, 240],
[50, 200, 290],
[120, 160, 230],
[80, 130, 300],
[90, 220, 320],
[90, 120, 300],
[40, 160, 240],
[50, 200, 290],
[120, 160, 230],
[80, 130, 300],
[90, 220, 320]
];


//calculating current month
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
console.log(currentMonth);

//c3 customisation
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto : '#chart',
data : {
    rows : data,
    type : 'bar',
},
axis : {
    x : {
        tick : {
            format : function (d) {
                return formatMonth(d);
            }
        }
    }
}
});

//select chart type
$("#chartType").change(function (evt) {
var chartSelection = $("#chartType").val();
var timePeriod = $("#SelectPeriod").val();
var chart = c3.generate({
    data : {
        rows : data.slice(0, parseInt(timePeriod) + 1),
        type : chartSelection
    },
    axis : {
        x : {
            tick : {
                format : function (d) {
                    return formatMonth(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

});

//select time period
$("#SelectPeriod").change(function (evt) {
var chartSelection = $("#chartType").val();
var timePeriod = $("#SelectPeriod").val();
var chart = c3.generate({
    data : {
        rows : data.slice(0, parseInt(timePeriod) + 1),
        type : chartSelection
    },
    axis : {
        x : {
            tick : {
                format : function (d) {
                    return formatMonth(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});

//function for months
function formatMonth(d) {
if (!d) {
return "JAN";
}
var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
return month = months[d];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

http://jsfiddle.net/jygh8obh/28/

HTML:

```
<select id="SelectPeriod">
    <option value="-1">January to this month</option>
    <option value="3">Last 3 months</option>
    <option value="6">Last 6 months</option>
    <option value="9">Last 9 months</option>
    <option value="12">Last 12 months</option>
</select>
```

JQ:

```
//select time period
$("#SelectPeriod").change(function (evt) {
    var chartSelection = $("#chartType").val();
    var timePeriod = $("#SelectPeriod").val();

    if (timePeriod == -1) timePeriod = currentMonth + 1;

    var end=currentMonth+2;
    var start=end-timePeriod;
    var data2=[];    
    data2.push(data[0]);    
    data2=data2.concat(data.slice(start, end));
    //alert(start+'/'+end+'='+data2)

    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
            rows: data2,
            type: chartSelection
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                tick: {
                    format: function (d) {
                        return formatMonth(d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

//function for months
function formatMonth(d) {
    var timePeriod = $("#SelectPeriod").val();

    if (timePeriod == -1) timePeriod = currentMonth + 1;

    timePeriod--;
    d=currentMonth-timePeriod+d;

    if (!d) {
        return "JAN";
    }
    var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
    return month = months[d];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @ dm4web, it works well. But i need to get the another value which i mentioned in the question `January to this month`. can you please tell m how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for the late update. is there any way i can make less code??

Answer (score 0):

solution of @dm4web is working good. And your last request solution : add this at the first line

```
var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
$('#SelectPeriod').find('option:first').val(currentMonth +1);
```

p.s. `currentMonth +1` was added because of reference is january. if you want february to month you must use like `.val(currentMonth +1)`

Comment: Thank you, sorry i dont have enough reputation points to make upvote.
If Possible let me know how to make it less code.""i am calling same chart function, thrice, is there a way to make it less code.""